# VSTest - DeploymentItem defined in testsettings file is not being deployed to TestResults folder

Tags: vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have a testsettings file with deployment items defined in it that deploys my files as I expect when I use it with MSTest.  However, when I use the same testsettings file with vstest.console.exe the items do not get deployed to the TestResults folder.  Do I need to do something differently to deploy specific files with vstest?

Here's the deployment section in the testsettings file:

```
<Deployment> 
    <DeploymentItem filename="C:\MyTests\testfile.txt" />
</Deployment>
```

Here's how I'm using it with MSTest that works:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:"C:\Tests\MyTests.dll" /testsettings:"C:\Tests\ts.testsettings"
```

And here's how I'm using it with VSTest that is not working:

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Tests\MyTests.dll /Settings:"C:\Tests\ts.testsettings"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure **DeploymentEnabled** flag is true in runsettings file. By default this is true. Changing it to false doesn't copy Deployment Items to the out directory of the TestResults folder.
Example:

```
  <MSTest>  
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>  
    <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>   
    <DeploymentEnabled>True</DeploymentEnabled>  
  </MSTest>
```

Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx